# "For each" loop in a lua table with key value pairs

Tags: lua, lua-5.2

Say I have a table defined like this:

`myTable = { myValue = nil, myOtherValue = nil}`

How would I iterate through it in a for each fashion loop like this?

```
  for key,value in myTable do --pseudocode
        value = "foobar"
  end
```

Also, if it helps, I don't really care about the key, just the value.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Keys which have no value (ie: are `nil`) do not exist. `myTable` is an *empty* table as far as Lua is concerned.

You can iterate through an empty table, but that's not going to be useful.

Furthermore:

```
for key,value in myTable do --pseudocode
    value = "foobar"
end
```

This "pseudocode" makes no sense. You cannot modify a table by modifying the contents of a local variable; Lua doesn't work that way. You cannot get a reference to a table entry; you can only get a *value* from the table.

If you want to modify the contents of a table, you have to actually modify *the table*. For example:

```
for key,value in pairs(myTable) do --actualcode
    myTable[key] = "foobar"
end
```

Notice the use of `myTable`. You can't modify a table without using the table itself at some point. Whether it's the table as accessed through `myTable` or via some other variable you store a reference to the table in.

In general, modifying a table while it iterating through it can cause problems. However, Lua says:

> The behavior of `next` is undefined if, during the traversal, you assign any value to a non-existent field in the table. You may however modify existing fields. In particular, you may clear existing fields.

So it's perfectly valid to modify the value of a field that already exists. And `key` obviously already exists in the table, so you can modify it. You can even set it to `nil` with no problems.

Variables in Lua are nothing more than holders for values. Tables contain values; `myTable[key]` returns a value. You can store that value in a variable, but changing the variable will *not* change the value of `myTable[key]`. Since tables are stored by reference, you could change the contents of the table in one variable and see the changes in another, but that is simply the *contents* of the table, not the table itself.

Comment: I would add that modifying a table in the same loop that you are using to parse it with pairs is considered "undefined behavior" in Lua. It might work in one Lua implementation, but not on other. There are safer alternatives, like using an auxiliary table to note the changes and then parse it to apply them.

Comment: @kikito: Not in this case. I've updated the post to explain.